# How to obtain list in sql query

Tags: sql, count, outsystems

In one application, I have a table with three fields, being Id, Name and count.

```
Id  |  Name  |  Value
1   |    A   |     5
2   |    B   |     9       
3   |    C   |     9
4   |    D   |     5
5   |    E   |     6
6   |    F   |     6
```

now, how can I obtain a cross table from the above? I mean, as follows:

```
Value | Count
----  | ----
5     |    2
6     |    2
7     |    0
8     |    0
9     |    2
```

can you help, please?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I can obtain existing values for the field value, but I don know how to populate all values in between... then... no ideia how to obtain count...

Comment: Where do the values 7 and 8 come from?  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: i need to populate all values in between maximum and minimum...

Comment: Are you trying to this ins OutSystems?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a tally table.  There are [many methods](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b5f13a70-6ff5-4704-83d6-e1cd68f172b5/select-the-numbers-between-two-numbers?forum=transactsql) for that.  You will use the tally table to number off all the values between min and max of your source table.  Once you have all the numbers between min and max, you will need to `LEFT JOIN` those into a a version of your table where you use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` to total the number of times each value appears.

Below Table A is the tally table.
Table B is your aggregated source table.

```
DECLARE @MinValue INT 
DECLARE @MaxValue INT
SET @MinValue = (SELECT MIN(Value) FROM dbo.MyTable)
SET @MaxValue = (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM dbo.MyTable)

SELECT number as Value, COALESCE(Count,0) AS Count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE number
    BETWEEN @MinValue AND @MaxValue
) AS A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Value, COUNT(Value) AS Count
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    GROUP BY Value
) AS B
ON A.number = B.value
```

Comment: The best way to make the table varies wildly based on rdbms, which hasn't been specified.